# GWT source build failure

Tags: java, gwt, java-8, ant, compilation

I'm compiling a snapshot (current master) of gwt from source.

When running the command ant clean dist-dev, it results in the below build failure.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\gwt_project\gwt\build.xml:53: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\gwt_project\gwt\distro-source\build.xml:23: Failed to copy C:\gwt_project\gwt\build\out\gwt-dev-merged.jar to C:\gwt_project\gwt\build\lib\gwt-dev.jar due to C:\gwt_project\gwt\build\lib\gwt-dev.jar
```

When running ant elemental dist-dev,it fails as below

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\gwt_project\gwt\build.xml:76: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\gwt_project\gwt\elemental\build.xml:20: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "idl\build" (in directory "C:\gwt_project\gwt\elemental"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have tried executing these commands from an admin command prompt to check if it is a permission issue. However it still fails with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Windows still holds the 'C:\gwt_project\gwt\build\out\gwt-dev-merged.jar' file, such that it can't be moved to the new location. Changing the ANT task from 'move' to 'copy' should fix the issue (in C:\gwt_project\gwt\distro-source\build.xml:23).